# Capistrano task deploy:assets:precompile takes an hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have a problem when deploing on production, executing environment for assets precompile task takes too long (20 to 60 minutes)

```
deploy:assets:precompile
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
      01 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
      01 Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.9 (latest) (c) 2009-2017 Michal Papis, P…
      01
      01 ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
      01 ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
      01 ** Execute assets:environment
      01 ** Invoke environment (first_time)
      01 ** Execute environment
```

And it holds on this moment. Strace outputs something like this

```
 rubygems/request_set/lockfile.rb\331\"rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb\264rubygems/resolver.rb\270rubygems/path_support.rb\267rubygems/uninstaller.rb\267rubygems/requirement.rb\272rubygems/version_option.rb\331 rubygems/local_remote_options.rb\331 rubygems/source_specific_file.rb\267rubygems/request_set.rb\331#rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb\331 rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb\277rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb\264rubygems/platform.rb\271rubygems/uri_formatter.rb\331\"rubygems/install_update_options.rb\266rubygems/name_tuple.rb\262rubygems/errors.rb\265rubygems/util/list.rb\271rubygems/util/licenses.rb\277rubygems/gemcutter_utilities.rb\264rubygems/security.rb\267rubygems/mock_gem_ui.rb\277rubygems/installer_test_case.rb\267rubygems/source_list.rb\273rubygems/command_manager.rb\273rubygems/install_message.rb\331)rubygems/resolver/vendor_specification.rb\3319rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/gem_metadata.rb\331=rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph.rb\331Grubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/resolution_state.rb\331Mrubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb\3315rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb\3317rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb\3317rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/ui.rb\331Krubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/specification_provider.rb\3313rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/errors.rb\331Arubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/log.rb\331Irubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/set_payload.rb\331Drubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/action.rb\331Hrubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_vertex.rb\331Irubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/delete_edge.rb\331Drubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/vertex.rb\331Rrubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_edge_no_circular.rb\331Qrubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/detach_vertex_named.rb\331Arubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/tag.rb\3312rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/state.rb\331,rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo.rb\331\"rubygems/resolver/specification.rb\276rubygems/resolver/molinill"..., 442032982) = 442032982
```

And htop says than CPU usage is near 100%.

So it seems that problem is somewhere on bundling gems for running environment, but i have no idea how can I deal with it. There's no such problem when i deploy to staging, and running rails conslole on production (which do the same gems loading I guess) doesn't take too much time.

Answer (score 1):

it is not recommended to compile assets on server, you should disable it and compile assets in local and commit assets and then deploy app.
[Rails guide for local assets compilation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation)